# how to automate creating firewall rules?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, firewall

There is a complex live system - few vlans. In each of them there are linux servers, and on every server there are services. Services connect together - for example service http on host A connect to service mysql on host B to port 3306/tcp.

I would like to automated mapping this type of configuration to a database and create firewall rules for each server - to allow only necessary connections between hosts.

I thought about:

- getting list of connections using netstat on each server (or logging connections from iptables?), and then putting it into database,
- visualise it using graphvis or something like it,
- create firewall rules based on rules from database
- create iptables rule to log connections which doesn't fit to previous rules and warn about them.

Is something what can be do better/faster/more automate way? Maybe there is no need to reinventing the wheel?

update: "hard" part is not creating firewall rules, but automated creating , and then manager list of needed connections.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion your best bet will be to use a [configuration management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_configuration_management) tool like [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/), [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/), [CFEngine](http://cfengine.com/) or [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home) so you can define your policies based on the host type and apply it to any new host.

Comment: ok - but i would like to do that more automated way - without writing "by hand" ansible/puppet rules. I don't know how system works - i would like to create rules more "live" - with information when system behaviour change (for example when server A instead connecting only to server B/mysql start to connect to server C/ssh)

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I used [ferm](http://ferm.foo-projects.org/) and a custom and simple bash script to generate  rulesets and insert it in the correct order vía "include" directive in **ferm.**

If you want logging connections, etc... you can use **ulog-mysql**, and save specific data matched with a specific iptables rule in mysql and graph whatever you want from this point forward.

Another possibility is use a [iptables role in ansible](https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles), probably you'll find the better role for your scenary.

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use fwbuilder (http://www.fwbuilder.org/). It's an opensource tool that manage a sort of kinds of firewall.